# Get variable hint as define from a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int):
        self.a: str = a
        self.b: int = b

hints = get_type_hints(MyClass())
print(hints)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
get_type_hints(MyClass)
```

and get this output:

```
{"a": str, "b": int}
```

I tried using `type()` but didn't get an optimal solution!

Comment: If you have the type hints already, why not build that object yourself? `hints = {k: v.__name__ for k, v in get_type_hints(MyClass.__init__).items()}` Unless you're working with objects with thousands of variables, isn't this optimal enough?

Comment: The attributes and annotations do not exist on the class, they're only created in `__init__` when it gets instantiated. If you'd put the annotations on the class itself of course…